# Selection in dataframe base on multiple condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am developping a dashboard using dash.
The user can select different parameters and a dataframe is updated (6 parameters).

The idea was to do :

```
filtering = []
if len(filter1)>0:
    filtering.append("df['col1'].isin(filter1)")
if len(filter2)>0:
    filtering.append("df['col2'].isin(filter2)")
condition = ' & '.join(filtering)
df.loc[condition]
```

But I have a key error, what i understand, as condition is a string.
Any advice on how I can do it ? What is the best practise ?

NB : I have a solution with `if` condition but I would like to maximise this part, avoiding the copy of the dataframe (>10 millions of rows).

```
dff = df.copy()
if len(filter1)>0:
    dff = dff.loc[dff.col1.isin(filter1)]
if len(filter2)>0:
    dff = dff.loc[dff.col2.isin(filter2)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **eval**:

```
filtering = []
if len(filter1)>0:
    filtering.append("df['col1'].isin(filter1)")
if len(filter2)>0:
    filtering.append("df['col2'].isin(filter2)")
condition = ' & '.join(filtering)
df.loc[eval(condition)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the masks using the `&` operator and only apply the merged mask once

```py
from functools import reduce

filters = []
if len(filter1)>0:
    filters.append(df.col1.isin(filter1))
if len(filter2)>0:
    filters.append(df.col2.isin(filter2))

if len(filters) > 0:
    final_filter = reduce(lambda a, b: a&b, filters)
    df = df.loc[final_filter]
```